# VISIO VBA - Position shapes inside existing shapes

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

I am using UserForms to drop shapes on the page instead of letting the user drag and drop from the stencil because I want the user to put in details and values into the shapes which are kept in sync with an Access database. 
The user is able to choose a "parent" Shape (which may or may not be a child shape itself): the new shape shall then be dropped in the middle of the parent shape and it should join the group of the parent.

This is my code:

```
Sub dropOBJ(id As Integer, descr As String, objType As String, prnt As Integer)

[...]

'Drop the shape
Dim mst As Visio.Master
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim pag As Visio.Page
Dim prntGrp As Visio.Shape

Set pag = Application.ActiveWindow.Page

If Not prnt = -1 Then 'Do this if a parent shape was chosen
    Set prntGrp = getGroup(prnt, "Prop.obj_ID")
    Set mst = Application.Documents.Item("Stencil.vssx").masters.ItemU("MasterShapeC")
    Set shp = pag.Drop(mst, prntGrp.Cells("PinX"), prntGrp.Cells("PinY")) 'drop in Parent
    shp.Group                                                             'init own group
    shp.Parent.Parent = prntGrp                                           'Add to prnt group
Else 'do this if no parent shape was chosen
    Set mst = Application.Documents.Item("Stencil.vssx").masters.ItemU("MasterShape")
    Set shp = pag.Drop(mst, 3, 9)                                         'drop at coordinates
    shp.Group                                                             'init own group
End If

'Write Values in Shape Props
[...]

End Sub
```

This works if the parent shape does not have a parent. If however, the parent shape has a parent itself, the new shape will not be dropped in the center but instead below and left of the parent shape, way out of the shape itself (grouping etc. will be fine, its just the position is wrong)

I digged around in the ShapeSheets and think the problem might be that the PinX und PinY Values are formulas for the first child shape. I tried reading the value of the formulas and using these numeric values for the pag.Drop method, but this does not change anything.

Maybe somebody has an idea how I can fix this.

Thanks

Edit: 
Ok the problem was that I was using the drop method of the page Object but the coordinates that were relative to the parent shape. Instead of pag.Drop I am now using prntGrp.Drop, to get the center of the parent shape I am using the width and height cells of it as the PinX and PinY Values still give me some strange results

Working code:

```
    Set prntGrp = getGroup(prnt, "Prop.obj_ID")
    xVal = prntGrp.Cells("Width") * 0.5
    yVal = prntGrp.Cells("Height") * 0.5
    Set mst = Application.Documents.Item("Stencil.vssx").masters.ItemU("MasterShapeC")
    Set shp = prntGrp.Drop(mst, xVal, yVal) 'drop in Parent
```